# Display non-existing data points in chart

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

I would like to display a simple chart in Tableau, with blue square marks for existing incidents (data points) and red ones for non-existing incidents.

The goal is to have a categorical matrix of existing as well as non-existing data points. But how can I display a mark for each non-existing data-point?

My current worksheet looks like this:
[image]

My desired worksheet should look like this (identical data source):

[image]

How can that be achieved? I tried the following calculated field, still the results of the calculation are only displayed for existing data points, thus always showing `TRUE`:

```
COUNT([Name]) == 1
```

Content of the csv file for data source:

```
Name,Category
Element A,Category 1
Element A,Category 2
Element A,Category 3
Element B,Category 1
Element B,Category 3
```

Comment: I achieved the incidence calculation following these instructions: https://community.tableau.com/message/173105#173105 ; The var `IsData` is calculated as follows: `IF(ISNULL(LOOKUP(COUNT([Name]),0))) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`, compute using `Name`. This calculated field tells me whether there is a data point or not (1/0). Now I have the problem to display the square marks in dichotomous colors according to `IsData`. How can I do that? Thanks for help.

Comment: New situation here: http://imgur.com/a/ZTX1M

Comment: make the calculation discrete (right-click and select "Discrete")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer with the help of [this article](https://community.tableau.com/message/173105#173105).

First, create a calculated field `IsData (discrete)` and turn it to discrete, compute using `Name`:

```
IF(ISNULL(LOOKUP(COUNT([Name]),0))) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Then, drag it into Marks shelf, then on Color, and set the colours accordingly:

[image]